# This may indicate the process failed to start. Error: spawn /usr/bin/python ENOENT error occurring when deploying python app with azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd

Hello Folks ,
I am facing issue in `Azure DevOps` while deploying `Python apps` and in the deployment time. I am facing this issue
Error:

> spawn /usr/bin/python ENOENT.